# Getting future date in calendar instead of today's date in Magento 1 issue

Tags: magento-1, calendar

This is my setup for the calendar:

```
Calendar.setup({
  inputField : 'scheduled_ajax_update',
  ifFormat : '%Y-%m-%d',
  button : 'scheduled_ajax_update_trig',
  align : 'Bl',
  singleClick : true
});
```

Its working fine except that I got a future date. See img attached:[image]

Any idea why I got this ?

Thx :)

Comment: the problem is current date is not showing in calendar. am i right?

Comment: @RamaChandran , yes, that's the problem :) or to get the value from the input(which has this format: `14-06-2017` ) as default date

Comment: I think it is take from local or server date. can you please check.

Comment: not sure about this, but I think you can pass a dateText param to the setup.

 dateText: 'your date'

Comment: getting this: `TypeError: this.getDateText is not a function`

Comment: Hi i understand the issue. This issue occurs only on edit page. not in add pages. (that means default value is there only this issue occurs) can you please confirm

Comment: You can check ifFormat : '%m-%d-%Y' it will resolve the issue

Comment: actually I use this format `%d/%m/%Y` it works. but the input value is not that I wanted. Is it possible to have that format and somehow hack the displayed value ?

Comment: May be try like this 
jQuery('#scheduled_ajax_update').change(function(){
    console.log(jQuery(this).val())
})

Comment: I don't have jQuery included. I would like to do it with prototype . Pls don't judge me :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61293/discussion-between-rama-chandran-and-chester).